# VB.NET System.StackOverflowException After Adding Redis

Tags: vb.net, redis

I have a timer with 300 interval which does this job

```
Try
    Dim command As String = db.ListRightPop("command").ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(command.Length)
    TextBox1.text += command
Catch
End Try
```

Globals:

```
Dim redis As ConnectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1")
Dim db As IDatabase = redis.GetDatabase()
```

It gives me a `System.StackOverflowException` after running the program for 3-4 hours.

Comment: When you get the exception, try looking at the stack trace.  Look for patterns where the same method is called over and over.  The information you've included in the question is not enough to determine the cause of your exception.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I also have a huge ram usage. When I first start the program it's about 100mb in couple hours it's going up to 3gb and it all happened after I started to use redis.